# C++ inheritance not working

Tags: c++, list, function, inheritance

I am making a game, in the game a have a list that holds the player, this list deals with the class Player. I also have a class the is a child of Player called HumanPlayer. I have added a a human player to the player list. but when I run a render function it doesn't render from humanplayer it renders from player. The render function is a virtual function, that should be overwritten but it not.

Here is where I define the list:

```
std::list<Player> playerList;
```

here is where I add a humanplayer to the list:

```
playerList.push_front(HumanPlayer(512,512,&entityList));
```

Here is where the render function calls the render:

```
if(!playerList.empty()){
    std::list<Player>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = playerList.begin(); iter != playerList.end(); iter++){
       iter -> render(canvas);
    }
 }
```

Comment: You are `slicing` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c,  polymorphism requires `pointers`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing what it called [Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c). In order for polymorphism to work you need to use `pointer`s or `reference`s. The most basic solution would be to use a `pointer` instead:

```
std::list<Player*> playerList;
```

but now you need to manage the memory and remember to `delete` all the instances you create. So as Collin suggested you `could` use some sort of `smart pointer` like [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). But ultimately you need to decided which makes more sense for your problem.

Comment: Using pointers changes a number of things in his code; in particular, there will be just one instance of each player, not many.  It's highly unlikely that `std::unique_ptr` would be appropriate here; `std::shared_ptr` _might_ be, but there's a good chance that the most appropriate pointer is a raw pointer.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thank you, amended answer

Answer (score 1):

Firstly - use pointers, secondly - do not forget to make your methods virtual.

Answer (score 0):

Your objects are being [sliced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), since you're storing a value type `Player` rather than a pointer.

Try this instead:

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<Player>> playerList;
playerList.push_front(std::unique_ptr<Player>(new HumanPlayer(512,512, &playerList)));
```